# EXSLT String Tokenizer Context

Tags: xslt, exslt

What is the current node context inside an EXSLT Tokenizer for-each loop? I do not seem to be able to query any nodes in the documents. example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize($renderList,',')">
   <xsl:variable name ="tag" select="."/>
   <xsl:value-of select = "//tag[@name = $tag]"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If I  hardcode `<xsl:value-of select = "//tag[@name = 'A']"/>` out side the for-each loop, the query works.

What is the context node inside the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem is that in the `xsl:for-each` the current document isn't the original source XML document**.

This should work:

```
<xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>
<xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize($renderList,',')">
    <xsl:variable name ="tag" select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select = "$vDoc//tag[@name = $tag]"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```